# How can I populate controls in a new dialog window from a TableView (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I am very new to Java and to programming and I am trying to build a small desktop app with a database for a school project.
I have a main window with a TableView populated from a MySql database and I added several buttons to add edit and delete entries. When clicking on the Add button, a new window pops up to insert the data (with TextField controls). It works just fine, and the table gets updated. However, I am unable to do the same for the Edit button. I want to get the selected item from the TableView and when I press the Edit button I want the TextFields in the new window to be populated with the data from the selected item. I have no idea how to make this work. I would really appreciate your help. I tried pretty much every single thing on Google.

Main Java:

```
package proiect;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class Languages {
    int langId;
    SimpleStringProperty langName;
    SimpleStringProperty langCode;
    SimpleStringProperty cName;


    public Languages(int langId, String langName, String langCode, String cName) {
        this.langId = langId;
        this.langName = new SimpleStringProperty (langName);
        this.langCode = new SimpleStringProperty (langCode);
        this.cName = new SimpleStringProperty (cName);

    }

}
```

Main Controller:

```
package proiect;

 import java.io.IOException;  import java.net.URL;  import java.sql.Connection;  import java.sql.DriverManager;  import java.sql.ResultSet;  import java.sql.SQLException;  import java.sql.Statement;  import java.util.ResourceBundle;  import java.util.logging.Level;  import java.util.logging.Logger;  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;  import javafx.fxml.FXML;  import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;  import javafx.scene.Scene;  import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;  import javafx.scene.control.TableView;  import javafx.scene.control.TextField;  import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;  import javafx.stage.Modality;  import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Tab1Controller {

    Connection cnx;

    Stage addLang;
    AddlangController ctrlAdd;

    Stage editLang;
    EditlangController ctrlEdit;

    int indexSelect;


    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    TableView<Languages> tlanguages;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Languages, Integer> langId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Languages, String> langName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Languages, String> langCode;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Languages, String> cName;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchlang;

    @FXML
    void add(ActionEvent event) {
        addLang.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    void deleteLang(ActionEvent event) {
        try {

            int poz = (int) tlanguages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            Languages lang = tlanguages.getItems().get(poz);
            int id = lang.langId;
            String cda = "delete from languages where langId = " + id;
            Statement stm = cnx.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate(cda);
            stm.close();
            load();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(Tab1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void editLang(ActionEvent event) {
        editLang.showAndWait();

    }

    @FXML
    void cancelLang(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    public void load() {
        tlanguages.getItems().clear();
        String cda = "select * from languages order by langname";

        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = cnx.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(cda);
            while (rs.next()) {

                int langId = rs.getInt("langId");
                String langName = rs.getString("langName");
                String langCode = rs.getString("langCode");
                String cName = rs.getString("cName");

                Languages lang;
                lang = new Languages(langId, langName, langCode, cName);
                tlanguages.getItems().add(lang);
            }
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tab1Controller.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        langName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().langName);
        langCode.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().langCode);
        cName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().cName);

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Proiect?characterEncoding=utf8", "root", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tab1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tab1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        load();

        //Get the window for "Add languages"
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Addlang.fxml"));
            BorderPane container = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            ctrlAdd = loader.getController();
            addLang = new Stage();
            addLang.setTitle("Add languages");
            addLang.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            Scene scena = new Scene(container);
            addLang.setScene(scena);
            ctrlAdd.ctrl = this;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tab1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Get the window Edit Languages
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Editlang.fxml"));
            BorderPane container = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            ctrlEdit = loader.getController();
            editLang = new Stage();
            editLang.setTitle("Edit languages");
            editLang.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            Scene scena = new Scene(container);
            editLang.setScene(scena);
            ctrlEdit.ctrl = this;

            tlanguages.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((object, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                indexSelect = (int) newValue;


            });

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tab1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } }
```

Edit Controller:

```
package proiect;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class EditlangController {

    Tab1Controller ctrl;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
     TextField lName;

    @FXML
     TextField lCode;

    @FXML
     TextField country;

     @FXML
    TableView<Languages> tlanguages;

    @FXML
    void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

    }

    private String apostrof(String s) {
        return "'" + s + "'";
    }

    @FXML
    void editLang(ActionEvent event) {

    }

        public void populate() {


 }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {


    }
}
```

Comment: Create a constructor in your Edit controller to accept a reference to the TableView's selected item. Then just bind it's values to your new scene's text fields. I'll try to write up a full answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample was not complete so I built a quick application from scratch that demonstrates how to do this.

Basically, you would need to pass the selected item from your `TableView` to the new controller when you create it.

Here is a complete listing of the sample program that demonstrates this (6 files):

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));

            primaryStage.setTitle("TableView Sample");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainController {

    // Define the FXML controls
    @FXML
    private TableView<Data> tblDataView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> colName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> colEmail;
    @FXML
    private Button btnDoThings;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Create sample Data objects for the TableView
        ObservableList<Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        dataList.add(new Data("Bob", "bob@email.com"));
        dataList.add(new Data("Harley", "harley@coolspot.com"));
        dataList.add(new Data("Jane", "jane@email.com"));
        dataList.add(new Data("Moby", "mobyboy@toocool.com"));

        // Setup the TableView columns to display the correct data
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        // Bind the list of sample data to the TableView
        tblDataView.setItems(dataList);

        // Set the action for the button
        btnDoThings.setOnAction(event -> doThings());

    }

    private void doThings() {
        // If no item has been selected from the table, do nothing
        if (tblDataView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) return;

        // Load the new window
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("EditorLayout.fxml"));

            // Create the new controller and pass the currently selected data item to it
            EditorController controller = new EditorController(tblDataView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

            // Set the controller to the loader
            loader.setController(controller);

            Stage editorStage = new Stage();
            editorStage.setTitle("Edit Item");

            // Centers the editor window over the current window
            editorStage.initOwner(tblDataView.getScene().getWindow());

            // Ensures the new window needs to be closed before the current window can be used again
            editorStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            editorStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            editorStage.showAndWait();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Here you will look to the `doThings()` method. You'll see that a new `EditorController` object is created and added to the `loader`. You can use that controller's constructor (next code listing) to pass the reference of the currently-selected item along for editing.

You can also reuse the same `EditorController` to add new entries to the list as well, by passing a `new Data(null, null)` through to the controller. You would also need to add it to the `TableView`'s underlying list, of course.

**EditorController.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditorController {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEmail;
    @FXML
    private Button btnSave;

    private Data data;

    // Constructor to accept the object to be edited
    public EditorController(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Bind the data to the textfields
        txtName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(data.nameProperty());
        txtEmail.textProperty().bindBidirectional(data.emailProperty());

        btnSave.setOnAction(e -> handleSave());

    }

    private void handleSave() {
        // Just close the stage
        ((Stage) txtEmail.getScene().getWindow()).close();
    }
}
```

This simple controller receives the selected row item from the `MainController` and then binds its data to the text fields. Any changes made to the data here is automatically updated back on the main window as well.

It is here that you could implement further abilities, such as allowing changes to be cancelled, etc. But this should get you started in the right direction of at least having the data available to manipulate.

**MainLayout.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="sample.tableViewSample.MainController">
    <children>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
            <children>
                <TableView fx:id="tblDataView">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name"/>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colEmail" prefWidth="200.0" text="Email"/>
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
                <Button fx:id="btnDoThings" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Do Things!"/>
            </children>
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**EditorLayout.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <VBox spacing="10.0">
            <children>
                <GridPane hgap="10.0" vgap="5.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Name:"/>
                        <Label text="Email:" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
                        <TextField fx:id="txtName" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
                        <TextField fx:id="txtEmail" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSave" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save Changes"/>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```